# Is the independence assumption broken when collecting data from two people who interacted with each other?

Tags: independence, assumptions

If data was collected from two participants who were interacting in an experiment, would this be breaking the independence assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, this would almost certainly break the independence assumption. If you're conducting a psychological experiment on two groups of twenty people and some of the subjects interact, then it is possible that the interaction would affect the results. (Depending on, of course, when the interaction occurred.)

Practically speaking, this will likely depend on sample size. For example, if you poll 10,000 people on whether they prefer Coca-Cola or Pepsi and two of the people you sample happen to be married, then the dependence between those two is likely negligible and needn't be considered when doing your analysis.

Oftentimes independence can't entirely hold. You as the analyst need to assess whether the data are *independent enough.* I generally consider whether the results would significantly be affected if the data were treated as independent. This will generally be a function of sample size and how related observations are to one another.